# ReSharper Test Runner runs all test within assembly instead of running just under only the selected folder

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I am trying to run NUnit unit tests within VS 2015 using ReSharper test runner.

What am I doing:

- Right click on a folder say "MyFolder" in VS 2015 Solution Explorer
- In the context menu I click on "Run Unit Tests" menu item. The "Unit
  Test Sessions" panel opens with the correct title "All tests from
  MyFolder".
- The "Unit Test Sessions" panel correctly shows the tree
  with only the TestFixtures and their Test cases within MyFolder
  However not only those test cases will be run instead *all* tests in
  the assembly.

**Please note:** *In many cases it will be hard to notice* *that other test cases are also run*, because no visual feedback on those. I mean no red / green, because the unwantedly ran tests are not in the unit test session tree. However if your tests say launching external process, you will see that something unwanted is happening. Also you can run the tests in debug mode, an place a breakpoint some other tests (what are not in the tree) your breakpoint will be hit.

As I have many unit tests in the assembly and they launches external process (Selenium driver for various browsers) this issue makes me run "all or nothing".
*(Except I open a test file individually and run via the source window. That feature works correctly, only the right clicked test will run)*

Is it a known issue, or just me?
Thanks in advance.

Additional info:

- Using VS  2015 Enterprise 14.0.23107
- JetBrains Resharper Ultimate 10.0.2
- NUnit 3.0.1
- Windows 7 x64

Comment: How do you use Resharper for NUnit 3.0 if it seems to be not supported yet?

Comment: I did not noticed it is not supported... Btw the issue is there too if I am using the 2.x nuget packages